# the membersInjector of dagger do not generate when i use javac command to compile some java files

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

i user javac command to compile some java files.
all dagger files are generated but expect of xx_membersInjector.
i use it for an android increase build.

when i compile the whole project, dagger works well !

could u tell me which situation can cause this type of files do not be generated if you know the reasaon?

sorry for my poor English....
the command look like this: >> i am sure my command is correct

javac -encoding UTF-8 -g -target 1.7 -source 1.7 -cp some android library:  the file witch need compile: the files which relate to the dagger -d some path

Comment: Why are you manually running javac instead of using the built in gradle build system?

Comment: gradle build system need a gradle project. i use javac because of i doing it for a android increase build. I just want to complies the file witch was edited. so i can't not build the whole project.......[cry]

Comment: And every android project comes with one.  Trying to do it any other way is just making life hard on yourself for no reason.